# How to upload image to node.js from iOS App?

Tags: ios, node.js, express, image-uploading

iOS Code, I want to use [upload image from ipad app to node js server using multiparty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354630/upload-image-from-ipad-app-to-node-js-server-using-multiparty)

Server is Node.js&express, upload.js path is in ./routes. I hope to use multiparty. but node-multiparty/examples/upload.js is not express . who can help me?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for someone to do this for you, which isn't going to get you very far. Have you tried yourself and hit a specific problem? If so, ask a question about that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code it's pretty similar to the one given in the example. You just gotta put the form.parse inside the route, like in this example

```
    var path = require('path');
    var express = require('express');
    var multiparty = require('multiparty');
    var util = require('util');

    var app = express();

    /*var staticPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '/public');
    app.use(express.static(staticPath));*/


    //Simulating web server
    app.get('/uploadImage', function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
        res.end(
            '<form action="/uploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
            '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
            '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
            '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
            '</form>'
        );
    })


    //This routes matters
    app.post('/uploadImage', function (req, res) {

        // parse a file upload
        var form = new multiparty.Form();

        //After your request body is parsed with multipart/form encoding
        //You can access to the files and the fields in that form
        //You may upload it to another image service
        form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
          res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
          res.write('received upload:\n\n');

          //The property that matter inside files object it's path
          //With that, you can write it in your server file system (fs) 
          //or data base or cloud service
          console.log('files received', files);
          console.log('fields received', fields);
          res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
        });

    })

    app.listen(3000, function() {
      console.log('listening');
    });
```

Make sure you install all dependencies
        npm install express multiparty

Comment: I have renameed it upload.js, command: node upload.js.   How to call it from iOS Client?  Where will images be saved? can you give me a complete project( iOS & Node.js). Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the example given, the iOS client sends something like this:

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------9051914041544843365972754266
Content-Length: 554

This message is sent to the nodejs server through the route /uploadImage with a post method and some data with some content type headers.

Inside the callback there's an argument called files. Read the comments pls.